# Is JBoss EAP 6.1.0 running in Ubuntu compatible with Java JDK 8

Tags: jboss, java-8, jboss-eap-6

I have deployed my JBoss EAP version 6.1.0 in my Ubuntu with JDK version 7. Now what should I do to run the same JBoss version (i.e. 6.1.0) with JDK 8?

Comment: I think jdk 8 is only supported from JBOSS EAP 6.3.3 onwards. I use JBOSS EAP 6.2.0 and couldn't get it to run under jdk 8.

Comment: but since my application is running successfully in jboss EAP 6.1.0, I cannot upgrade the jboss version. Is there any other way to run it on jdk8?

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on running Java 8 you will have to either switch to JBoss EAP 6.3.3+ or switch to WildFly 8+.

There is no support for Java 8 in EAP 6.1.